# Issue compiling libmagic program, magic_open, MAGIC_MIME and MAGIC_CHECK undeclared

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, libmagic

I've been trying to use `magic.h` and `magiclib` in my program to help with file type identification. However when I try compiling the program it states `magic_open`, `MAGIC_MIME` and `MAGIC_CHECK` are undeclared causing an error.

I've tried the following command (`magicTest.c` being my program)

```
gcc magicTest.c -o magicTest -lmagic
```

without success

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include </usr/include/linux/magic.h>

int main(){
   struct magic_set *magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME|MAGIC_CHECK);
   magic_load(magic, NULL);
   printf("magic output: '%s'\n", magic_file(magic, "myText"));

   return 0;
}
```

Below is the actual errors and output i'm receiving

```
magicTest.c: In function ‘main’:
magicTest.c:7:30: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘magic_open’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    struct magic_set *magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME|MAGIC_CHECK);
                              ^
magicTest.c:7:41: error: ‘MAGIC_MIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    struct magic_set *magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME|MAGIC_CHECK);
                                         ^
magicTest.c:7:41: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
magicTest.c:7:52: error: ‘MAGIC_CHECK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    struct magic_set *magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME|MAGIC_CHECK);
                                                    ^
magicTest.c:8:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘magic_load’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    magic_load(magic, NULL);
    ^
magicTest.c:9:35: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘magic_file’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("magic output: '%s'\n", magic_file(magic, "myText"));
                                   ^
magicTest.c:9:11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("magic output: '%s'\n", magic_file(magic, "myText"));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

after running the command as jww suggested, shown below:

```
find /usr -name magic.h 2>/dev/null
```

My output is:

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/linux/magic.h
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/linux/magic.h
/usr/include/magic.h
/usr/include/linux/magic.h
/usr/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/magic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-39/include/uapi/linux/magic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-37/include/uapi/linux/magic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-38/include/uapi/linux/magic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32/include/uapi/linux/magic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-41/include/uapi/linux/magic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36/include/uapi/linux/magic.h
```

Thanks again!

Comment: `#include </usr/include/linux/magic.h>` --> `#include <linux/magic.h>`

Comment: I'm still encountering the same issue, even after making this change to my code. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It looks like you are missing a header. Is `libmagic-dev` package (and possibly `libmagickcore-dev`) installed?

Comment: I'll double check to make sure. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I've done a sudo apt-get install on both packages and still the issue resides. could I be linking the libraries wrong? thanks

Comment: Perform a `find /usr -name magic.h 2>/dev/null` and report back with the results. You can add the additional information to your question by clicking *Edit* in the lower left-hand corner of the question, and then making the changes.

Comment: Sorry, missed this: *"could I be linking the libraries wrong"*. You are experiencing a compiler error, not a linker error. The compiler cannot find [`magic.h`](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/magic_open.3.html) (assuming the header has `magic_open` and firends). Eventually you will need to add a `-I` option for the compiler. You may need a linker option too, but you are not that far along (yet).

Comment: Actually, looking at the `linux/magic.h` on my system, it doesn't define any functions at all.  It just has a bunch of macro values.  Is the `/usr/include/magic.h` different from `/usr/include/linux/magic.h`?  I don't have the one in `/usr/include`.